# what is the difference between grails link ,createlink and resource tags

Tags: grails

Is there any difference between grails link ,create link and resource tags and I want to know when to use each tag as per my knowledge the createlink tag has depricated

Comment: read these link http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html, http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/resource.html, http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/link.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's simple:

`g.createLink` generates only the url, like `/aaa/bbb/222`, based on controller/action/params for example

`g.link` generated the `<a>`-HTML-tag, using the `g.createLink` to generate the url to be put into the `@href` attribute

`g.resource` outputs a path to a resource file, available under `web-app` folder

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css',file:'style.css')}" />`

produces

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

**CREATE LINK** is soemthing power full when u come to knowing the absolute or relative path in using likes inside a gsp page.

Let assume i have the following path /yourapp/controller1/view1
Instead of using

```
  <a href="{grailscontext.thensomebaseurlstuff}/"+controller/view /> ,
```

which fails according to some context using the below will make it easy.

```
 <a href="${createLink(action: 'list')}">my link</a>
    <g:createLink url="[action:'list',controller:'book']" />
```

And ,**glink** is the above implementation using `taglib` form.. does the same effect as above but being in taglib makes reduce some computation or create some am not sure.

```
g.link("text of the link here", action:"foo", controller:"bar")
```

**ResourceTags** is no wonder its something help full and important in attaching either an `image`,`css` and `js` folder/file resource into a grails application.

```
// generates "/shop/css/main.css"
<g:resource dir="css" file="main.css" />
// generates "http://portal.mygreatsite.com/css/main.css"
<g:resource dir="css" file="main.css" absolute="true" />

// generates "http://admin.mygreatsite.com/css/main.css"
<g:resource dir="css" file="main.css" base="http://admin.mygreatsite.com"/>
```

Alloha!